# Truncating Text based on combined characters of two variables

Tags: php, wordpress, function, truncate

I am using a custom function to truncate text based on an argument which states the number of allowed characters. Here is my code:

```
function bm_best_excerpt($length, $ellipsis, $content) {
$text = $content;
$text = strip_tags($text);
$text = substr($text, 0, $length);
$text = substr($text, 0, strripos($text, " "));
$text = $text.$ellipsis;
return $text;
}
```

ON any page, I can truncate text by grabbing a Wordpress custom field (which contains a string of text) and running it through this function like so:

```
<?php $excerpt = get_field('long_description'); ?>
<p><?php echo bm_best_excerpt(70, ' ... ', $excerpt); ?></p>
```

This works great, and displays the first 70 characters of `$excerpt`. I want to modify this function, so it first counts the number of characters in a title (above the description) and then uses any leftover characters for this description.

To illustrate this, lets say I want to allow for 80 characters total. My RAW HTML is below:

Here is a Title that is fairly long

Here is a description followed by some Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

I want the TOTAL amount of characters between the title and description to be 80. The title has 35 characters, which leaves 45 characters left for the description.

How would I modify the above function to allow for the counting of an additional content variable (as an argument) and then the subtraction against the `$length`? I would want the function to look something like this:

```
function bm_best_excerpt($length, $ellipsis, $content1, $content2) {
```

Where `$content1` is the title and `$content2` is the description

Comment: function bm_best_excerpt($length, $ellipsis, $content, $content2='') { $text=$content.' '.$content2; ?

Comment: not sure I understand what you are trying to convey

Comment: You just need to add the content onto the end of the title (separated by a space for readability) and truncate the lot to 80.

Comment: related: You should try and see if you can use the mysql function LEFT() to only fetch a limited number of chars from your db in the first place ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to add the strings together and process as one:

```
function bm_best_excerpt($length, $ellipsis, $content, $content2='') {
    // default content2 to empty string, allowing use of old method to still be valid
    $text = $content.' '.$content2; // add the second content to the end of the first
```

Comment: see my answer below...I would like to treat them as separate variables

Comment: I tried this, but again (like my solution) the title is left out.

Comment: The only issue is that the title needs to be wrapped in h2 tags plus a link, like so:  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_field('resource_name'); ?></a></h2>

Comment: How can I adapt "$text = $content.' '.$content2;" to use that format?

Comment: I can make the permalink another variable, and pass it as an argument?

Comment: This line will not process the permalink for some reason:  $text = '<h2><a href="'.$link.'">'.$header.'</a></h2> <p>'.$desc.'</p>';

Comment: the strip_tags in your function will remove any html so you need to just use it on the $header __OR__ add a line at the end of the function to construct the link (you'll need to pass $link to it too)